# JS file not loading

Tags: jquery, javascript

I am trying to link to my javascript file in WordPress to manipulate the navigation bar. Here's the call in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'scrolling_navbar_enqueue_js' );
/**
* Load custom JS script for scrolling navbar
* @return void
*/
function scrolling_navbar_enqueue_js(){
    wp_register_script( 'navbar-scroll', 'http://www.classyclutter.net/wp-content/themes/foodiepro/assets/js/scrolling-navbar.js', array('jquery'), '1.1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'navbar-scroll' );
}
```

Here is my scrolling-navbar.js file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
     console.log(jQuery(window).scrollTop())
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > 220){
                    //This alert shows up in the console log
                    //but is not longer actually in the file on the server
                    alert("Working now");
        jQuery('#menu-menu-bar-under-header').addClass('sticky-nav-menu');
        if(is_user_logged_in()){
            jQuery('#menu-menu-bar-under-header').addClass('user-logged-in-nav-menu');
        }else{
            jQuery('#menu-menu-bar-under-header').addClass('no-user-nav-menu');
        }
    }
    if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < 221){
        jQuery('#menu-menu-bar-under-header').removeClass('sticky-nav-menu');
        if(is_user_logged_in()){
            jQuery('#menu-menu-bar-under-header').removeClass('user-logged-in-nav-menu');
        }else{
            jQuery('#menu-menu-bar-under-header').removeClass('no-user-nav-menu');
        }
    }
});
});
```

And for reference, this is the current site, but this is how it is supposed to be working (the navigation bar should scroll with the page).

I just can't seem to figure out why WordPress isn't loading my javascript file. I use the debugger in the console to check the sources and it has yet to show up.

Comment: wht do you mean "not loading"? have you checked the browser consolde, checked if the url is correct?

Comment: That's the thing - it wasn't showing up in the console. Thanks to Mostafa I was able o get it to load though.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set dependencies at third parameter put it with array() or array('jquery') if you want to depend on jQuery

```
wp_register_script( 'navbar-scroll', 'http://www.classyclutter.net/wp-content/themes/foodiepro/assets/js/scrolling-navbar.js', array(), '1.0.0', true);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Turns out I also forgot a '(' and had an extra '$' in there s well. Now it loads the javascript, but it won't refresh it. I had an 'alert("Working now");' call in it, but now that it's working I deleted it. However, the console still shows it is loading the older version with the 'alert()' in it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @dmcrider, you need to change the version parameter or just do hard refresh.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I changed the version to '1.1.0' and did a hard refresh (ctrl+F5) but it still has the alert. The FTP download of the .js file is correct, but the one the browser is loading in the console is not.

Comment: @dmcrider, time to restart the browser maybe :)

Comment: @MarkKaplun Closed it, opened it, force closed it, reopened it, and it's still loadng the old .js file. I've also changed the versioning again in the wp call, but nothing. **EDIT** In Edge it's loading the right one, but not Chrome (the one I've been using to test)...